# how copy text with font in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, fonts, copy

How can I copy a text from an `EditText` to the clipboard with it's set typeface?

See following code

```
 btnz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name =et.getText().toString();
            Typeface myfont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "ComialUnicoder.ttf");
            tv.setText(name);
            tv.setTypeface(myfont);
        }
    });
    btncopy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            String font = tv.getTypeface().toString();
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", font);
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

Comment: `i want code for copy text with font?` you **can't**: you can only copy text from a string. If you want, you can set the same font on the destination EditText. Also mind that `I want code` is never a great formula, here.

Comment: I don't know how you want it, or what your buttons do, but I'm thinking you can do that hard-codedly (if that's a word. LOL). I mean with the use of a switch case.